# Is there a way to work around the transaction item limit in DynamoDB?

Tags: transactions, amazon-dynamodb

The current limit of items in a dynamoDB transaction is 25.

If I need to update more than 25 items in a single partition, and roll them back if they've been updated, how can I do so?

I've implemented [row versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html#bp-sort-keys-version-control), so am keeping the record current status on the v0 record.

Can I include some kind of flag on a v0 item to indicate it is taking part in a wider transaction, and roll it back if need be, and if so how do avoid deadlocks?

Comment: I don't think there is a way, wanted to know were you able to solve it ?

Comment: @dDarkLORD unfortunately, no, I did think of putting an intermediate layer in which handles larger transaction by using one of the 25 items to store transaction data, but decided it'd be a lot of effort

Answer (score 0):

Posted On: Sep 6, 2022

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/09/amazon-dynamodb-supports-100-actions-per-transaction/

> The maximum number of actions in a single transaction has now increased from 25 to 100.